# $x^2-\log x = u $ asymptotic behaviour

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

Find the asymptotic behaviour as $u \to \infty$ of the solutions of
$x^2-\log x = u$.
Is there a standard method to solve this kind of problems? May the fact that we obviously know the derivative of $f^{-1}(x)$ help?
A similar problem was: "given $u=x+\tanh x$ show that, if $u \to \infty$ then 
$x=u-1+e^{2-2u}+O(e^{-4u})$

Comment: There is indeed a standard method to solve these kinds of problems.  You can find an example of it in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/551720/5531) and the in the answers linked therein.  I'll be happy to give a complete answer here if you need additional help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by Newton's method. Obviously, for $x^2 - \log x = u,$ the first guess would be $x = \sqrt{u},$ (since $\log x \ll x,$ for $x$ large). The first Newton step ought to give you an excellent approximation. As for your "similar problem", what you wrote makes no sense (since there is a mix of $x$s and $u$s), so you might want to edit. That said, the solution should be very similar, since for $x\gg 1,$ we know that $\tanh x$ is very close to $1,$ so obviously $x = u-1$ is the first guess, and you can get the second by Newton.

Comment: @d.zeffiro, this approach can be modified to obtain the behavior of the other root which tends to $0$ as $u \to \infty$.

Comment: ok, thank you Antonio and Igor. I would also add that the hypothesis to apply Newton method hold, since the function is clearly convex and we start with a guess in which the function is positive.